# Most efficient way to search multi-tree data structure

Tags: java, search, optimization, arraylist

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to search through a multi-tree than what I have been doing. I recently built a multi-tree data structure for a project that is illustrated below.
[image: Multi-Tree data structure using ArrayLists]

The cave would hold the parties in an array list. The different parties would hold different creatures. Different creatures would hold different items.

I needed a way to search the whole tree to match an object to an attribute it had such as index. This is a snippet of my program that searches through every ArrayList to see if either a party, creature, treasure, or artifact matches an int I call index.

**Edit**(Explaining my code)
The classes Party, Creature, Treasure, and Artifact all have attributes such as index, name, type, etc. The multi-tree has the Cave set as the root note. Cave has an ArrayList that can contain a number of Party objects. Each Party has an ArrayList that can contain a a number of Creature objects. Each creature has two array lists one to hold Artifact objects and one for Treasure objects.

Below I am searching to see which party, creature, artifact, or treasure holds the specific index that I am searching for. I do this by iterating over parties, with each party I look in the creatures, and with each creature I look in the artifacts and treasures. That is why I have so many for loops inside of for loops :(.

```
case 0 :
            int index =                 Integer.parseInt( stat );
            for ( Party p : SorcerersCave.theCave.parties ) {
                if ( index == p.getIndex()) {
                    generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + p );
                    break;
                } else {
                    for ( Creature c : p.members ){
                        if ( index == c.getIndex() ){
                            generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + c );
                            break;
                        } else {
                            for ( Treasure t : c.inventory ){
                                if ( index == t.getIndex() ){
                                    generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + t );
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            for ( Artifact a : c.artifacts ){
                                if ( index == a.getIndex() ){
                                    generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + a );
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I feel this code is too complicated and is difficult to follow. The code works but its an ugly stain on my otherwise really good looking code. I've been looking around to find a better way to do this, or even a way to improve it.

Note* Project requirements forbid us from placing every object in the same ArrayList.

Comment: I bet cyclomatic complexity analyzers are just going to *love* this code...In all seriousness, let's eschew the Java code and enumerate the goals of the algorithm on paper.  If you can do that, then you could figure out a slightly cleaner way/approach to this problem.  In all actuality, I don't see any "trees" - in fact, the code snippet you've provided isn't sufficient enough to give you a good answer.  Could you provide some context to the code you have here, such as what the rules you're imposing are?

Comment: I had no idea there where tools that could tell you how complicated your code was! Cant wait to try it out. That said I have ran through this on paper and I cannot see a way other than cycling through as I've done above. I'm a relatively young programmer so I'm still trying to build my tool set and knowledge.

Comment: if getIndex is a common method across all classes, would you consider abstracting it out to a super class?
one final resort could be using instaceof or reflection if you absolutely need it.

Comment: I think break will only break out of the inner loop.

Comment: @isaach1000: `break` will break out of the loop *at that level*.  Higher level `break` statements will break out of higher level loops.

Comment: Exactly but isn't the point to find the **first** match, whether it is a party or a creature, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes could implement a common interface `SearchableByIndex` that would look like this and which would be implemented by every class in the tree:

```
public interface SearchableByIndex {
    public SearchableByIndex searchByIndex(int index);
    public int getIndex();
}
```

Then `Cave`, `Party` and `Creature` require this code:

```
public SearchableByIndex searchByIndex(int index) {
    if (getIndex() == index) {
        return this;
    } else {
        for (Party party : parties) {    // or Creature creature : members etc.
            SearchableByIndex found = party.searchByIndex(index);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Treasure and Artifact's version:

```
public SearchableByIndex searchByIndex(int index) {
    return (getIndex() == index) ? this : null;
}
```

And instead of your nested looping you have there, you'd have

```
case 0:
    int index = Integer.parseInt(stat);
    SearchableByIndex foundItem = SorcerersCave.theCave.searchByIndex(index);
    if (foundItem != null) {
        generateInterface.theGame.printOutput("\t" + foundItem);
    } else {
        // print out that the item was not found
    }
    break;
```

While the `searchByIndex()` method on every class may seem repetitive, it's the OOP way to do it. This way, every class would take care of searching all its contents. In your case, all classes would have the code very similar (the only change will be the line with the for loop), but you can consider this to be an accident - any class could contain any data it wants and no other classes should care about how it stores its data.

In future, if one of your classes would hold more searchable data (`Treasure`, `Artifact` and `Hostage`?), or you'd like to change the structure of its data (consider [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), if you can!), you would just have to change the `searchByIndex()` method in the particular class.

Also, only the class containing the data should know *how* it contains it. The way you now have it, some other class that invokes the searching knows exactly how data is stored in every class - this should not be. If one class changes, it breaks internal code of other classes. For example, the `Cave` class should state in its documentation that it holds e.g. different `Party` instances and that it can give out some of them if you search for it by `searchForIndex()`.

Comment: @Slanec- Is there anyway you can email me? I have a couple questions about HashMap that I feel are beyond the scope of this question. My email is displayed on my profile.

Comment: @Dustin E-mails are private, so I can't see yours. Email me> JanecekPetr squigglyAtSign seznam.cz

Answer (score 2):

> Project requirements forbid us from placing every object in the same ArrayList.

(And presumably, a `HashMap` or `TreeMap` is forbidden too ...)

Without some kind of secondary data structure for mapping `index` values to the objects they refer to, you have **no choice** but to do a tree traversal.  So on average, your "find an object" code will be `O(N)` if there are `N` objects ... with a rather large constant of proportionality.

(Presumably, whoever placed that constraint on the problem didn't care about performance.  You should take the same attitude ... especially given the context set out in your comments.)

You could improve the code in a couple ways that will make it more readable and (most likely) more efficient.

1. Use "break to label" so that the inner loops exit to the end of the outer loop when they get a hit.  (Assuming that's what you want.)
2. Use temporary variables to avoid evaluating multiple method calls each time you lookup an element in the container hierarchy.  **UPDATE**: it looks like you've just rewritten the code to do that ...

---

> ... project requirements dictate that each object needs to be instantiate in a multi-tree data structure as shown in the diagram I posted.

But do they expressly forbid a secondary data structure?  Or have you just *assumed* that you are not allowed to do that?

Comment: Project requirements forbid having a secondary data structure. I asked the professor this same question and he responded by typing "no" 34 times into his response without explaining anything.

Comment: @Dustin I bet you'll look into in next semester, but if you're curious and want to learn something new and harder today (again), look at what [Hash maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_map) are capable of. The idea is that you'd have one [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) containing all elements of the tree, where `index` would be keys. This way, you could search the whole tree instantly (`O(1)`) in one line of code instead of linearly (`O(n)`) in nested for loops and/or method invocations. The best data structure always depends on its usage.

Comment: @Dustin - He is saying to you "efficiency doesn't matter" for this exercise.  This is a **programming exercise** not a project to build the worlds next killer D&D app (or whatever).  Do the exercise ... and move on.

Comment: Actually, there is an important lesson for you here.  In the real world, it is *often* the case that efficiency is NOT an important criterion for a software development project.  It is *often* more important that the code works, meets the *functional* requirements, is maintainable, and is delivered on time.  And if performance is not important, you should not waste your time (and the bosses money) by optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the for-each loop instead:

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(stat);
for(Party party : parties){
    if( index == party.members.get( c ).getIndex() ){
        generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + party.summary );
        break;
    } else {
        for(Creature creature : party.Creatures){
            // etc etc.....
        }
    }
}
```

That would make the code a little easier to read.  It does have the disadvantage that you do not have a counter built into the loop.

EDIT: This article may clarify:
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

Comment: I did not know about for-each constructs. My only question to this is if I have multiple parties each filled with different creatures, how would this search the creatures of each party? And the treasures and artifacts of each creature?

Comment: See: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with  It might help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty odd constraint set, but in the spirit of tree traversal without needing to modify the original data structure at all, why not write the naive recursive traversal function as a set of overloaded methods?  It might look like this:

```
public Object search(int index, Cave c) {
  if (c.id == index) return c;

  for (Party p : c.parties) {
    Object result = search(index, p);
    if (result != null) 
      return result;
  }

  return null;
}

public Object search(int index, Party p) {
  ...
}
```

And so on.

Comment: With the change OP did (for-each loops instead of usual indexed loops), it shouts loudly for recursion like this.

Comment: Indeed.  This is usually presented as the textbook method for traversing trees.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a more regular structure?  Something along these lines (I'm using pseudocode):

```
interface INode { ... stuff kept in nodes is described here ... }
interface ITree extends INode { bool HasId(int id); ITree[] Children; }

INode SearchTreeForId(ITree[] children, int id) {
  for each (child in children) {
    match = (child.HasId(id) ? child : SearchTreeForId(child.Children));
    if (match != null) return match;
  }
  return null;
}

// Then...
{
  node = SearchTreeForId(SorcerersCave.theCave.Parties, id);
  if (node != null) generateInterface(...);
}
```

Comment: I wish but sadly no, project requirements dictate that each object needs to be instantiate in a multi-tree data structure as shown in the diagram I posted

Comment: Hi Dustin, I'm not sure what a multi-tree is -- a collection of trees, perhaps?  The ITree interface is what provides that structure.  Anyway, good luck with your program.

Comment: According to my professor a multi-tree is a data structure which each "node" ie. the Cave, parties, creatures, etc. Can have 0<=x children. Unlike a BST where each node may have 0<=2 nodes. That’s how he explained it at least.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Observe that the ITree interface specifies an *array* of children, not a *pair* of children.  This characterises a "multi-tree" in your professor's terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Do a depth first search using a helper method.

```
private Interface IndexObject
{
    // Interface will be used in dfsList
    public int getIndex();
}

private Interface ListObject extends IndexObject
{
    // For classes with sublists
    public ArrayList<IndexObject> getList();
}

public void search(int index) {
    Object found = dfsList(parties, index);
}

// Helper method
public Object dfsList(ArrayList<IndexObject> aList, int index) {
    for (IndexObject obj : aList) {
        if (obj.getIndex() == index) {
            return obj;
        }
        else if (obj instanceof ListObject) {
            IndexObject found = dfsList(obj.getList(), index);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since your entry point is Cave object , one can think of making a unique string like primary key that represent the whole Cave object(Cave,Part,Creatures,Treasures,Artifacts) for eg concatination of those field by which you want to search for eg if you want to search artifact by index 3 you can make a string like

```
C-P-C-T/A
```

where each letter represent unique indexes in 'this' class so in this case it might be like

```
3-4-32-A3
```

where 3 represent 3rd cave,4 represent 4th party .... till A3 represent artifact 3rd.

Hope you had found solution better than this ,if please share.